# Recursively counting the number of characters in a string. (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, recursion

I need to write a recursive function that utilizes just two string methods, .empty? and .chop.
No, I can't use .length (Can you tell it's homework yet?)

So far I'm stuck on writing the function itself, I passed it the string, but I am unsure on how to recursively go through the characters with the .chop string method.  Would I just have a counter? Syntax for this thing seems tricky to me.

```
 def stringLength(string)
  if string.empty?
     return 0
  else
     .....
  end
 end
```

I wish I could put more down, but this is what I'm stuck at.

Comment: Think about recursion as a function calling itself with different parameters and see what you get from there.  Where would you call stringLength again and with what parameter?

Comment: The two things to keep in mind, or that you'll need, with any recursive function are the *termination clause* (you've got that), and the call to itself (as dbyme's answer shows) usually with slightly different arguments (as anterlersoft says). That's your normal starting point. Usually, I make the termination clause return the final answer too, but it'll obviously depend on the function/context. Play around until you find a style that suits you, as once you've got it in your head you'll find recursion very natural. Ruby isn't particularly suited to recursion though, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return 1 + stringLength(string.chop)`

Thats your missing line.  Here is an example of how this will work:

```
stringLength("Hello") = 1 + stringLength("Hell")
stringLength("Hell")  = 1 + stringLength("Hel")
stringLength("Hel")   = 1 + stringLength("He")
stringLength("He")    = 1 + stringLength("H")
stringLength("H")     = 1 + stringLength("")
stringLength("")      = 0
```

Comment: Wait... there's an unwritten rule for questions tagged [homework]: you don't *give* them the answer, you *lead them to* the answer. **Edit**: Actually it *is* written (sort of) in the definition of the [homework] tag.